# What are the differences between HC estimators and their small sample properties?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, covariance-matrix, estimators

I am currently using R to run regression with the following code:

```r
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)

reg <- lm(Y ~ x1 + x1_sq + x2 + x2_sq + x1x2 + d2 + d3 + d4, df)
coeftest(reg, vcov = vcovHC(reg, type="HC1")
```

And have realized that I am specifying -type="HC1"- out of convention$-$I have always just used this one. I understand that this is a heteroskedastic-consistent estimator (White, 1980) and utilizes a degrees of freedom correction, but the -sandwich- package includes 5 different estimators. There is HCO, the standard "sandwich" estimator $\hat{\varepsilon}^2$, HC1, the one I use and am used to using, which includes the d.f. correction such that $\frac{n}{n-k}\hat{\varepsilon}^2$, and then HC2-HC4 which all take interesting forms:
$$\text{HC2}: \omega_i=\frac{\hat{\varepsilon}^2}{1-h_{ii}}$$
$$\text{HC3}: \omega_i=\frac{\hat{\varepsilon}^2}{(1-h_{ii})^2}$$
$$\text{HC4}: \omega_i=\frac{\hat{\varepsilon}^2}{(1-h_{ii})^{\delta_{i}}}$$
where $h_{ii}$ are the hat values, $\bar{h}$ is their mean, and $\delta_{i}=min\{4,\; h_{ii}/\bar{h}\}$ (Formulas obtained from [This set of slides](https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/teaching/AER/Ch-Validation.pdf).

I am currently having troubles understanding the *functional* differences between these estimators. i.e. what are the benefits and tradeoffs of using one over the other? Are there cutoffs for number of observations for which one would be preferred to the next?

Comment: I recommend reading [Long & Ervin (2000)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1526/72b624b44b12250363eee602554fe49ca782.pdf) on the matter.